# Как по нажатию кнопки открыть картинку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Ссылка на код: https://ideone.com/fork/foBQeQ

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button


from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 0)
Config.set('graphics', 'width', 370)
Config.set('graphics', 'height', 345)

class АлфавитApp(App):
    def addoperation(self, instence):
        open.

    def build(self):   
        gl = GridLayout(cols = 5, spacing = 20, padding = 30)


        gl.add_widget( Button(background_normal=('img/A.png'),on_press = self.addoperation))
        gl.add_widget( Button(background_normal=('img/B.png'),on_press = self.addoperation))
        gl.add_widget( Button(background_normal=('img/C.png'),on_press = self.addoperation))
        gl.add_widget( Button(background_normal=('img/D.png'),on_press = self.addoperation))
        gl.add_widget( Button(background_normal=('img/E.png'),on_press = self.addoperation))

        gl.add_widget( Button(background_normal=('img/F.png'),on_press = self.addoperation))
        gl.add_widget( Button(background_normal=('img/G.png'),on_press = self.addoperation))
        gl.add_widget( Button(background_normal=('img/H.png'),on_press = self.addoperation))
        gl.add_widget( Button(background_normal=('img/I.png'),on_press = self.addoperation))
        gl.add_widget( Button(background_normal=('img/J.png'),on_press = self.addoperation))

        gl.add_widget( Button(background_normal=('img/K.png'),on_press = self.addoperation))
        gl.add_widget( Button(background_normal=('img/L.png'),on_press = self.addoperation))
        gl.add_widget( Button(background_normal=('img/M.png'),on_press = self.addoperation))
        gl.add_widget( Button(background_normal=('img/N.png'),on_press = self.addoperation))
        gl.add_widget( Button(background_normal=('img/O.png'),on_press = self.addoperation))

        gl.add_widget( Button(background_normal=('img/P.png'),on_press = self.addoperation))
        gl.add_widget( Button(background_normal=('img/Q.png'),on_press = self.addoperation))
        gl.add_widget( Button(background_normal=('img/R.png'),on_press = self.addoperation))
        gl.add_widget( Button(background_normal=('img/S.png'),on_press = self.addoperation))
        gl.add_widget( Button(background_normal=('img/T.png'),on_press = self.addoperation))

        gl.add_widget( Button(background_normal=('img/U.png'),on_press = self.addoperation))
        gl.add_widget( Button(background_normal=('img/V.png'),on_press = self.addoperation))
        gl.add_widget( Button(background_normal=('img/W.png'),on_press = self.addoperation))
        gl.add_widget( Button(background_normal=('img/X.png'),on_press = self.addoperation))
        gl.add_widget( Button(background_normal=('img/Y.png'),on_press = self.addoperation))

        gl.add_widget( Button(background_normal=('img/Z.png'),on_press = self.addoperation))

        return gl



if __name__ == '__main__':
    АлфавитApp().run()
```

Comment: Посмотрите как создать [mcve]

Comment: @Viktor Tomilov суть вопрос ясна "Как по нажатию кнопки открыть картинку?" (в рамках [kivy] библиотеки) из заголовка. Если остались какии-то сомнения, посмотрите на анимацию в [существующем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/790944/23044). Зачем препятствовать новым ответам по этому вопросу?

Answer (score 3):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import os
import string

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class Alphabet(App):
    def addoperation(self, instance):
        modal = ModalView(size_hint=(.8, .8))
modal.add_widget(Image(source=instance.background_normal))
        modal.open()

    def build(self):   
        gl = GridLayout(cols=5, spacing=20, padding=30)

        for letter in string.ascii_uppercase:
            gl.add_widget( Button(background_normal=(os.path.join('img', letter, '.png')), on_press=self.addoperation))

        return gl


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Alphabet().run()
```

Для вывода информации пользователю обычно в любом приложении используются модальные окна. Я привел вам пример именно с таким окном.

Answer (score -2):

Во-первых, боже, никогда не используй русский в коде (для примера АлфавитApp).

По твоему вопросу нужны уточнения.. если говорить в-общем - ответ простой, для примера, возьмём кнопку А у которой фоновой изображение = "img/A.png", и по нажатию на которую отрабатывает метод addoperation, теперь, например, ты можешь дополнишь функционал метода addoperation так, чтобы он отдавал новый лейбл с другим фоновым изображением (т.е. фактически возвращал изображение).

Comment: Мне нужно, чтоб он возвращал новое окно с другой картинкой, или в этом окне открывал, но была возможность вернуться на начальный экран. Код немного изменил.
https://ideone.com/nGUU9s

Comment: ну так а что не так ? при нажатии на кнопку твой метод должен возвращать (чисто для примера, вариантов много) Widget c определённым фоновым изображением. Можешь поискать в [документации](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html?highlight=widget#module-kivy.uix.widget) по слову "background".